# Can you configure a default or backup sink?

Tags: serilog

In a dotnet core app, if one configures mssql as a sink via appsettings, how can you configure a "backup" sink such as a file?  So if serilog cant write to a given sink, it tries to write to the 2nd.

Is the Selflog what I need to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serilog doesn't have a feature like that, as of this writing, but it should be possible to implement by [creating your own Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink) that wraps the primary sinks and manages the error handling to perform the fallback to "backup" sink(s).

You might want to look at the code of [Serilog.Sinks.Async](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async) for inspiration, as it shows you a way of wrapping multiple sinks into one which could be a starting point.